# How should I load an image once and pass it around in a multithreaded C# app?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I'm writing an app whose purpose is to find images within a folder and present them to the user asking how they should be cropped. With all of the jumping I do from language to language on a daily basis, I tend to get my best practices and concepts jumbled up, and this is such a case.

Program flow goes like this: you're presented with the main form, with a browse button (that you could alternatively drop a folder onto). When you select a folder, it opens another form that scans the selected folder for .jp[e]g and .tif[f] images and presents them in a list, asking which of them you'd like to crop, and some other options. Then it goes back to the main form which goes through the list of selected images from that form, and within a `BackgroundWorker` for each one it loads it into a cropping form, then crops it and saves it.

For prototyping I handle the loading of images a bit messily; it loads all the images in the folder for the selection form, then it loads each selected image again in the cropper one-by-one, and then one more time in the main form to be cropped and saved. For large images, this could make the task time-consuming, as this app would handle TIFF source images up to about 4000px<sup>2</sup> in a worst-case scenario.

I would like to think that there is a way to just load each `Bitmap` once into some sort of global array, but that would be Visual Basic or VB for Applications. Since I'm using a `BackgroundWorker` I also have to worry about thread safety and whether or not C# will yell at me about trying to access something in an unsafe manner. Any ideas as to how I can accomplish the app's purpose while limiting the number of times a single image is loaded into a `Bitmap` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since according to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) the Bitmap class instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe I see 2 options:

- performant but a bit risky
  Load everything as a Bitmap object and add all those Bitmap objects to a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)... the access is thread-safe and very fast since the implementation is mostly lock-free...
- a bit less performant but not risky
  Load all files as [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) into a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx). when you need a Bitmap you just create a `MemoryMappedFile` (which will use the same memory already occuppied by the onece you created before thus extremely fast) and let the Bitmap load its content from there... when your app shuts down or you want to cleanup you just go through the Dictionary and get rid of those `MemoryMappedFile` objects...

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: one more object oriented than the other but harder to implement:

A) Create some class (eg, Document, BitmapDocument, or whatever) that holds a List where you add all of your images.  Don't worry about multithreading, just lock the List every time you add an image. Depending on what you do with the Bitmaps, you might need to lock them too.  (locking is not hard in c#, eg lock(someVariable){ ... } )   Making copies of the Bitmaps (that are already loaded into the List inside) as different controls use them should not require too much memory/time (since those would be RAM operations).  The complication arises when the main application has to pass this "document" class to all child controls and forms.  Once every control knows the "document" instance, any additions to it are immediately available.

B) Create some class where the List is marked internal and static, such that any class in your project can view it and use it.  This way you are using a sort of "global" array, but not quite global.  It is only visible inside your project (due to the "internal" tag), and it is still held inside a class.  Note that you'll still need to use C#'s locking mechanism to make everything thread-safe.

Note that instead of accessing class members directly, you might consider writing methods to manipulate them and lock the objects appropriately.  (This would be the correct programming practice.)  For B, just create methods that are marked "internal" and "static".

I'd personally use B (muck quicker to implement and debug), especially for prototyping, and since using it makes it not too hard to move on to A in the future.

Furthermore, if you use (B)'s approach of internal static objects and functions, you can write some function like GetBitmap(string path) that loads images from disk and also holds a buffer of all recently loaded images such that threads don't have to load from disk twice.

Comment: I'll keep these methods in mind for passing objects around like that in anything I write that isn't threaded... As Yahia said below, instanced Bitmaps aren't guaranteed to be thread-safe, and I found that List(T)'s aren't either.